# Delete from multiple tables where id does not match

Tags: mysql

I have about 10 tables like:
cities, districts, town, etc. All have school_id column in them.

I want to delete school_id from all tables where there is no match in school_id when compared to schools table. I can do this easily for one table. Like this:

```
DELETE FROM cities
 WHERE school_id NOT IN (SELECT s.id 
                        FROM schools s)
```

For districts table:

```
DELETE FROM districts
 WHERE school_id NOT IN (SELECT s.id 
                        FROM schools s)
```

My questions is there a way to combine all these queries in one?

Comment: Are you able to update the design schema of the DB? you should set school_id as foreign key and forget about this manual tasks, DB as itself would prevent this kind of noisy data.

Comment: @DanielAranda - I cant set that as foreign key for all tables. It is being used in so many tables.

Comment: @NoviceMe can't is not the right word for this, 'don't want to' is more like it

Comment: @arnoudhgz - Some tables have different storage engines.

Comment: I know, but you could have say that earlier, I was refferring to the 'it is being used in so many tables'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a simple `JOIN`

```
delete a, b from cities a
join districts b using(school_id)
where school_id not in (select id from schools)
```

add a `join` for each table to deleted..

```
delete a, b, c from cities a
join districts b using(school_id)
join tables3 c using(school_id)
where school_id not in (select id from schools)
```

Comment: op said he has about 10 tables.. and how do you achieve it using join here?

Comment: he can join as many (well there is actually a limit) tables as he want.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard - This does not work if in one table lets say cities dont have any school_id that is missing. But other tables do have ids that are missing.